# print a matlab structure in table format

Tags: matlab

I am trying to visualize data stored in my data structure so that I can spot patterns in them.

The data which I am trying to visualize is stored in following structure format:
master_data.(A).(B).{values}
Here, A are various insturments which define the data. Lets call these instruments A1, A2, A3 and so on. B are various properties of these instruments. Lets call them B1, B2, B3 and so on. Each insturment of A has these same properties B1, B2, B3 and so on. Now, values are cell arrays having 5 different double values. So, we might have masterdata.(A1).(B1) having values 1,2,3,4,5 and masterdata.(A1).(B2) having values 5,4,3,2,1.

now I want to print these values in the following way to easily visualize them

```
          B1       B2      B3 .....

A1        1         5
          2         4
          3         3
          4         2
          5         1
A2

.
.
.
```

I understand there might be better way to store data than structure but I am most comfortable working with structures and so I have generated my data in this format. Also, I can write a loop to iterate through all elements of structure and print out values but I am not sure how to take care of formatting issues.

I request you to let me know how to print these values in the required format(we may convert data to a more suitable data type if it gets the job done). I am not giving sample code for iterating to print existing structure as I suspect there is a better way to convert my structure to something like table or map and simply printing that structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call your master_data MD. Here is how you can do it:

```
fields=fieldnames(MD);
res=[];
for i = 1:numel(fields)
  res=[res;struct2dataset(MD.(fields{i}))];
end
```

Comment: Thank you Marounen. Your method does solve some of the issues I am facing with visualization of data. However, the result does not preserve names A1, A2,... I need to preserve names of A1,A2 as well in the final result. Also, I need to print out the end result so that I can look for patterns on paper. I am not sure how to effectively print res dataset on paper.

Comment: Upon further thought, I can add another variable inside structures A1, A2,.. as names "A1" ,"A2" to preserve names of instruments inside dataset res. That solves another issue. Final issue is how to print out dataset "res". I cannot find any option to print or display "res" in matlab workspace or variables. Please help with this.

Comment: type in `res` without semi colon

Comment: typing "res" without semicolon printed table but instead of values, it showed [1x5 cell]. However, I can copy the result from variable window to excel and print from there. Thank you very much for you help.